# Path quadraticBezierTo: curve pass the control point

Tags: dart, flutter, bezier

I have a `CustomPainter` that looks like this:

```
class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  Offset left, top, right, bottom;

  MyPainter({this.left, this.top, this.right, this.bottom});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint pp = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 10;

    Paint p = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2;

    Path ph = Path();

    ph.moveTo(left.dx, left.dy);
    ph.quadraticBezierTo(top.dx, top.dy, right.dx, right.dy);

    canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, [left, top, right, bottom], pp);
    canvas.drawPath(ph, p);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

And this is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9mHp.jpg

However I want the curve line, pass the control point. Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC7XG.jpg

How can I do that?!

Comment: @pskink What is that (3, 5) in first cubicTo and that (9, 3) in second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to calculate internal control point `P1` coordinates based on needed point `top`

At first, roughly evaluate parameter `t` for that point. Let it is `1/2` (if `top` lies near the middle of curve). Using quadratic Bezier formula:

```
P(t)  = P0 * (1-t)^2 + 2 * P1 * t * (1-t) + P2 * t^2
top {for t=1/2} = P0 * 1/4 + P1 * 1/2 + P2 * 1/4
P1 = 2 * top - (P0 + P2) / 2
```

in components:

```
P1.dx = 2 * top.dx - (left.dx + right.dx) / 2
P1.dy = 2 * top.dy - (left.dy + right.dy) / 2
```

and finally

```
 ph.quadraticBezierTo(P1.dx, P1.dy, right.dx, right.dy);
```

Comment: It worked, but only when the control point is at the middle! What about other positions?

Comment: In general case you need some additional information. Quadratic Bezier curve is parabola, but it is not possible to build general parabola by three points (in school method there is limitation - we know that parabola axis is vertical)

Comment: [Blue' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735648/if-5-points-are-necessary-to-determine-a-conic-why-are-only-3-necessary-to-dete/1736999#1736999) shows uncertainty